# How to retrieve text from firebase realtime and display it on a fragment

Tags: java, firebase

I'm new to Android studio and I want to display texts from firebase realtime on a fragment but I can't do it, I already connected firebase to my Android project
If someone can give me a code that can help me thank you

I tried to see videos on youtub but all videos only give how displayed on an activity and not on a fragment
Whereas I have to work on a fragment since I use a tablelayout

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What have you tried to achieve that?